# How to write a code that automatically executes a function based on the user input?

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to write a code that automatically executes a function based on the user input. I have my real functions in my code blocks but just to make things simple the example is simplified. The code that I wrote until now looks like this:

```
#Function lists
def a1():
    return 'a'
def b2():
    return 'b'
def c3():
    return 'c'
def d4():
    return 'd'
def e5():
    return 'e'
def f6():
    return 'f'
def g7():
    return 'g'


while (cond):
    try:
        command=input('Enter a integer that matches the function\'s\ name')
        funcname=

        print(funcname)

    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong value. please enter an integer')
```

After this point, the while loop must print out a prompt asking the user to input an integer again that matches up with the functions created.

The parts that I am working on are these:

- the command that matches function's name is entered based on user input.

  ```
    command=input('Enter a integer that matches the function\'s\ name')
  ```
- the user input integer is matched up with the function name that contains it. ex) user input=1, the function matched=a1()

  ```
    funcname=
  ```
- print the function results

  ```
    print(funcname)
  ```
- if a character is entered in to the user input instead of integers send error.

  ```
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong value. please enter an integer')
  ```
- The while loop condition that would create a proper loop that prints a prompt to users in order to get user inputs after former input is executed.

  ```
        while (cond):
        .
        .
        end
  ```

This is so far as I planned and wrote the code but obviously, it has a long way to go to get executed correctly.

How to make this code work?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to gather the functions to be considered into a list. This list can then be searched for the matching function.

A decorator can be used to do this:

```
def make_func_list():
    """Return a decorator which tracks which functions it's applied to.
    The decorator will have an `all` attribute to list these.
    """
    functions = []
    def wrapper(fn):
        functions.append((fn.__name__, fn))
        return fn
    wrapper.all = functions
    return wrapper

# Create the decorator
fl = make_func_list()

# Apply the decorator to each function to be included in the executor
@fl
def fn3(): return 3

@fl
def fn1(): return 1

@fl
def fn2(): return 2

# Can enumerate the list and solicit input based on index:
# (adjusted to be indexed from 1)
for n, (name, fn) in enumerate(fl.all):
    print(f'{n + 1}: {name}')

response = int(input('Enter number: '))
name, func = fl.all[response - 1]
print(name, func())

# Or search the names instead (this one would search for any input):
response = input('Enter number: ')
for name, func in fl.all:
    if response in name:
        print(name, func())
```